# jQuery: Submit form when AJAX finishes

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

So I have a form that on clicking submit, I want to do some validation, before it submits. Pretty straight forward I think. So I setup a submit handler on the form and wanted it to do the AJAX check, and when it finishes, if its all good, go ahead and submit as usual.

I tried this, and it failed for very obvious reasons:

```
$.when(checkUsername()).done(function (a) {
    checkTitle();
    checkMessage();

    if (userValid && titleValid && messageValid) {
        return true;
    }
});

return false;
```

`checkUsername` is a `$.post`, while `checkTitle` and `checkMessage` are just checking if any characters are in those fields. Each of the functions relatively validates `userValid`, `titleValid`, and `messageValid`, setting those values true or false. The two input fields and text area field has a blur attached with each of the related functions, so even before the user clicks submit, the form is validating.

So obviously, with the return false at the end, the form would never submit. BUT, I originally had the valid check outside the done (where the current return false is), and if the user entered 3 valid items, then erased a field and didn't leave it/blur, and directly clicked submit, it would still submit, because with the AJAX still processing, the fields hadn't undergone a second round of checking.

Essentially, I want the form to wait on submission until the AJAX finishes. But the `submit()` function will process its return before the AJAX finishes, and I can't put it in a done, since I need the AJAX to trigger on on the submit. Essentially, a catch 22.

I came up with something that I feel is a messy way of doing it, but the only method I can think of at the moment, and could use advice on if this is the only way to do it, or what other options I have. I am aware I could just submit the form via AJAX, but I'm hoping to see what options are available. This is the messy method:

```
if (validated) return true;
else {
    $form = $(this);
    $.when(checkUsername()).done(function (a) {
        checkTitle();
        checkMessage();

        if (userValid && titleValid && messageValid) {
            validated = true;
            $form.submit();
        }
    });

    return false;
}
```

In this case, there is a master validate variable only set by the ajax, and the system resubmits when done.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is the way to go. The .done method has a different context because of it's asynchronous execution, meaning that your validation method always will return false upon calling.

Answer (score 0):

Because your validation is async you need to do a little trick. you can use the `.data()` function to check if your form data was validated. if not do the validation. in the validation you can set the `validated` data to true and trigger the `submit` via jquery again.

One additional note, i hope you still validate the data you receive by the form server side again, because javascript validation can be bypassed.

you need to replace the  `$(form)` with your form element or the query to your form.

```
$(form).submit(function(event) {
    //check if already validated
    if (!$(this.data("validated")) {

        doValidation();
        //prevent form form submitting because validation is in progress.
        event.preventDefault();
    }

});



function doValidation() {

    //do you validation suff.
    $.when(checkUsername()).done(function(a) {
        checkTitle();
        checkMessage();

        if (userValid && titleValid && messageValid) {
            //mark the form as validated
            $(form).data("validated", true);
            //trigger submit via jquery
            $(form).submit();
        }
    });

}
```

Or you go the *ajax* way and post your form with `$.post` (only works if you have no file input element).

```
$.post($(form).attr("action), $(form).serialize());
```